# C# : Cannot run selenium tests in parallel while using a Chrome profile

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run tests in parallel , however I am not able to. It triggers only one failing the other. I am using Chrome profiling option ("user-data-dir") to launch Chrome. If I disable this option, the tests run just fine in parallel. Can somebody tell me what I could be missing?

The argument that I have added is

```
public string ChromeProfilePath= "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data";

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument(string.Format("user-data-dir={0}", ChromeProfilePath));                    
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

It invokes the driver session with the current chrome profile successfully when a test is run but fails when run in parallel (invokes one instance, test it and fails the rest).
The error I receives for the failed one is

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: failed to write prefs file
```

Note: I am using NUnit as test framework, C# and Selenium

Comment: Can you add the full code of how you are initializing the driver?

Comment: @C.Peck I have updated. Please let me know if I need to share more details.  Thanks